# Java selenium show popup if exception occure

Tags: java, selenium, exception, joptionpane, webautomation

I am working on automation, using java selenium using chrome driver to get data from webpage.

I want to set like a popup message like joptionpane if exception occurs.

1. if chrome driver path is incorrect, it should show popup with message.
2. if internet disconnects while selenium running, also show popup.

I tried try catch block but not working perfectly. Can you guys show me a sample piece of code to achieve...

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
   try{ 
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe"); 
       throw new IllegalStateException("description of the exception");
  }catch(IllegalStateException e){ 
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "ChromeDriver Path incorrect","ErrorMsg", 
                                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
       System.exit(1); 
   }
```

Comment: please show what you have tried and what problems you are having

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  try{
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  
     "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
   throw new IllegalStateException("description of the exception");
     }catch(IllegalStateException e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "ChromeDriver Path incorrect","ErrorMsg", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         System.exit(1);
  }                                         Popup throwing even if path is correct. I am new for programming so i don't know much about

Comment: really what do you think your code is doing?

Comment: Really I don't know.. Pls help

Comment: Hi @dhinan , Replace the line **throw new IllegalStateException("description of the exception");** with code ** if (java.nio.file.Files.notExists(Paths.get("C:\\chromedriver.exe",LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
   throw new TestCaseReaderException("File does not exist at path - "+path);
   }**

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code snippet , which I have used to handle similar problem while reading the test data. You can throw custom exceptions for your validations and at last catch statement show the popup box with the error message.

```
 @DataProvider(name = "data")
        public String[][] getDataForTestCases()  {
            String[][] arrayExcelData = null;
            try {
                Log.info("Reading the Test Case.");

                // code to read the file and create data provider array

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.info("Problem while Reading Test Case   - " + e.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new Frame(),
                        "Problem while Reading Test Case   - " + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);     
             }
            Log.info("Done Reading Test Case Driver File.");
            return arrayExcelData;
        }
```